# How to use the set if less than (SLT) statement in a for-loop in MIPS 32?

Tags: for-loop, assembly, mips, mips32

I'm working on some homework and my issue is I'm supposed to include the SLT (set if less than) line in this for-loop assembly but I'm not sure how to do that. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729275/mips-assembly-branch-if-less-than) helpful but I can't use the BLT (branch if less than) statement, the professor did introduce macros but this question specifies to use SLT. I ended up just using it in my assignment statements but I feel like this barely passes for what the professor is asking for, here's the statement: `slt $t2, $t0, $t1  #t2 holds y = 1 if i < x`. It just doesn't really fit with the code at all, it doesn't serve a purpose I feel like it should be involved with the for-loop, any advice?

Here's the basic for-loop the assembly represents:

```
for (i=0; i<x; i++) 
   y = y * 2;
```

Here's the assembly code in MIPS 32:

```
.text
.globl main
main:
    li $t1, 7          #test val num of iterations, x = 7
    li $t0, 0          #t0 is our counter i = 0
    #li $t2, 1         #another way to assign y = 1
    slt $t2, $t0, $t1  #t2 holds y = 1 if i < x
    
loop:
    beq $t0, $t1, end  #if (i)t0 == (x)7 end loop
    add $t2, $t2, $t2  #body, y = y * 2
    addi $t0, $t0, 1   #add 1 to i, t0
    j loop             #jump back to the top
end:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: The `slt` needs to be inside the loop, along with `beq` as part of implementing a branch-if-`!(i<x)` as the loop condition.  Unless you optimize (for MIPS) the `<` into `==` so you can just use `beq` inside the loop.  The `slt` here is used as an initializer for `y`, separate from determining the loop trip-count, but your C doesn't show any initialization for `y` so we can't really comment on whether that's equivalent or what optimization is being applied.

Comment: Right I just didn't know how to put the SLT into the loop but I'm thinking if I put it right above the beq statement and then use the beq with the new variable that's set to 1 or 0 I can do this

Comment: Uh, yeah, if you look at how a pseudo-instruction like `bge $t0, $t1, target` assembles, you can see that pattern of slt / beq is standard for MIPS.

Comment: haven't seen bge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the `slt` is not serving the purpose of loop control since it is not involved in the loop.

The condition `i<x` is a dynamic condition as part of the iteration of loop, because `i` changes each iteration.

You might have noticed this deficiency had you single stepped to debug it.

But one problem is that you're not working with great pseudo code as `y` is never initialized.  We could still work with this but let's note that you have chosen to initialize `y` in some way that is not part of the given pseudo code.

What you have written in assembly language has equivalent pseudo code of:

```
y = i < x;              // bad: outside the loop and modifying y
for (i=0; i!=x; i++)    // bad: using condition i!=x
    y = y + y;          // good: valid for y = y * 2;
```

Can you see the several ways that this pseudo code is not the same as the original?  `y` is initialized to something not in that original, and the loop exit condition, `i!=x` is different from that original.  This pseudo code is not logically equivalent and will not run the same as the original.

---

Let's work from more fundamental principles and logical transformations, so you can see some of the issues:

```
for (i=0; i<x; i++) 
   y = y * 2;
```

We first convert this for-loop into an equivalent while-loop, because the while loop is more explicit:

```
i = 0;
while ( i < x ) {
    y = y * 2;
    i++;
}
```

Next, we convert this while-loop into the if-goto-label style of assembly language, again, because this is more explicit and each such step gets us closer to assembly language.  You will really start to see what is in the loop and what isn't, even though this is still pseudo code (fyi, this if-goto-label is allowed in C).

```
    i = 0;
loop1:
    if ( ! (i < x) ) goto loop1Done;  // Exit loop when i < x is false
    y = y * 2;
    i++;
    goto loop1;
loop1Done:
```

The first thing to note is that in the if-goto-label style of assembly language, if we want the program to do something else we use an if-goto.  Hopefully you can see that as a consequence of the semantics of if-goto, the natural operation is to tell the processor when to exit the loop — rather than when to stay in the loop as is done in C — and hence the negation of the condition (which can be handled several ways by MIPS).

Next, we can clearly see that the relational operation `i < x` (and its negation) are required inside the loop, and as such must be repeated each iteration of the loop.

The operation `if ( ! (i < x) ) goto ...` is legal C code, though can be restated more in pseudo code as: `if ( i < x is false ) goto ...`.

The `slt` can be used as you describe with operands `i` in `$t0` and `x` in `$t1`, so that part was good, but the result need to go to a new temporary register, instead of clobbering the original value `y` (that was unspecified in the orignal pseudo code).  Let's imagine using `$t10` as this alternative temporary.  So, `slt $t10, $t0, $t1`, and note the placement of it *inside the loop*.

Now to test the conditional branch part of the condition test.  We want to test that the result of the `i<x` comparison is false, and branch to exit the loop when so.  Such a branch needs to test `$t10` since that holds the result of `i<x` from `slt`, and to test that this boolean is false, we would use `beq $t10 $0 loop1Done`, which says if `$t10` is equal to false (`$0` is always false) then do the goto/branch that exits the loop.

Left as an exercise for the reader is the completion of the logical transformation from if-goto-label pseudo/C code into assembly code.

---

Also note from the above discussion that your original pseudo code does not stand alone: an initialization of `y` is necessary, so in order to actually run this MIPS translation code, you'd would have to add such initialization (if the register for `y` just happened to be 0 as a simulator would initialize it, then the loop would be most meaningless since y = 0 * 2 would do nothing different, repeatedly).

Comment: If you look at the `slt` as `y = 0 < x;` it's a lot less bad (although it's a missed optimization to not use `$0` there); the comment on the asm is just wrong.  Or it's shortening to the point of being imprecise, e.g. should say less than what the initial `i` value will be.

Comment: It's a weird loop, though; I wonder if it's trying to achieve correctness with negative `x` for something for the `i<x` => `i==x` transformation, even if that means running 2^31 or so iterations to wrap around in that rare case?  But no, if the initial `y` was `1` in the normal case, you need to leave it unchanged, not set it to zero.  Also, `addi` will trap on signed overflow, and they specifically used it instead of `addiu`.  (Unless this is some kind of simplified MIPS without trapping add so `addu` doesn't need to exist, as well as not having branch delay slots)

Comment: Oh, I had been thinking that this code was written by the professor as an example and was presumably correct for something.  But no, it's a student attempt, so yeah you're correct to just consider it a mistake.

Comment: Okay thanks again! I just added an assignment statement for y and then put the slt statement right above the beq statement so it branches if the temp is ever equal to zero meaning the i was not less than x

Comment: yeah it was poorly written, I wasn't sure how to incorporate the slt but didn't realize the beq just referred to equalness so that doesn't help with making sure it remains less than @PeterCordes